# Laravel 5.1 : Error on install new

Tags: php, xampp, laravel-5, composer-php

When I am running `laravel new blog` or any name, I get the following error:

```
Crafting application...
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeException: Argument 2 passed to GuzzleHttp\Adapter\StreamAdapter::createResponseObject() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Adapter\StreamAdapter.php on line 67 and defined in C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Adapter\StreamAdapter.php:71
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Adapter\StreamAdapter.php(67): GuzzleHttp\Adapter\StreamAdapter->createResponseObject(Object(GuzzleHttp\Message\Request), NULL, Object(GuzzleHttp\Adapter\Transaction), Object(GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream))
#1 C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Adapter\StreamAdapter.php(52): GuzzleHttp\Adapter\StreamAdapter->createResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Adapter\Transaction))
#2 C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(193): GuzzleHttp\Adapter\StreamAdapter->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Adapter\Transaction)) #3 C:\U in C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Adapter\StreamAdapter.php on line 71

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeException: Argument 2 passed to GuzzleHttp\Adapter\StreamAdapter::createResponseObject() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Adapter\StreamAdapter.php on line 67 and defined in C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Adapter\StreamAdapter.php:71
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Adapter\StreamAdapter.php(67): GuzzleHttp\Adapter\StreamAdapter->createResponseObject(Object(GuzzleHttp\Message\Request), NULL, Object(GuzzleHttp\Adapter\Transaction), Object(GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream))
#1 C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Adapter\StreamAdapter.php(52): GuzzleHttp\Adapter\StreamAdapter->createResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Adapter\Transaction))
#2 C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(193): GuzzleHttp\Adapter\StreamAdapter->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Adapter\Transaction)) #3 C:\U in C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Adapter\StreamAdapter.php on line 71
```

I don't understand how this can happen. [Here is my PhpInfo file](https://66bb63bd94982dd00c34e510270513d6fc05e330-www.googledrive.com/host/0B-hG6EcZsP5uMnB5UE1pdXJlT0k/)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was simple. I was running PHP CLI from PHP7 and not XAMPP/PHP5. Only have to uncomment the `extension=php_curl.dll` line.

Comment: `composer global update` would be a good point to start. 
In my case I had no curl extension for php 7 installed, nor the zip. Since I'm on Ubuntu, `sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl php7.0-zip` did the trick.

Comment: @ruuter You just saved my life!